# Doctrine many to many: has user liked the article?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, many-to-many

I have 2 Entities

User 
Article
and a “likedByUsers” Many To Many relationship between both.

When I show an article, I want to know if the user has liked it so a heart icon is shown.

I've got this in the ArticleRepository:

```
public function findOneBySlug($slug,$userId): ?Pack
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->andWhere('p.slug = :val')
        ->setParameter('val', $slug)
        ->addSelect('COUNT(u) AS userLike', 'p')
        ->leftJoin("p.users", 'u', 'WITH', 'u.id = :userId')
        ->setParameter('userId', $userId)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult()
    ;
}
```

But it throws an error:

> Return value of App\Repository\ArticleRepository::findOneBySlug() must be
>   an instance of App\Entity\Article or null, array returned

I want to add "userLike" (bool) to the Article returned entity. Anyone can help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calling `addSelect(...)` on a query builder might change the return type / format.

in your particular case, the former db result was something like `[... all the article properties ...]` which hydration and the `getOneOrNullResult` turns into one `Article` or null.

the new format looks like

`[... all the article properties ..., userlike]`, which hydration turns into `[Article, userlike]` which can't possibly turned into one Article or a null result, because it's a "more complex" array.

**So you have to use a different result fetcher.** Depending on what the caller of your function expects as a return value (I would expect an article ^^) you maybe should rename the function or add a virtual property on article to hide the userlike or something, so you can return just the Article or null.

So the solution that I would choose:

```
$result = $this->createQueryBuilder(...)
   //...
   ->getSingleResult();
if(!$result) { 
    // empty result, obviously
    return $result; 
}
// $result[0] is usually the object.
$result[0]->userLike = $result['userLike']; 
// or $result[0]->setUserLike($result['userLike'])

return $result[0];
```

btw: `$this->createQueryBuilder($alias)` in a repository automatically calls `->select($alias)`, so you don't have to `addSelect('... userLike', 'p')` and just do `addSelect('... userLike')`

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. It works perfectly. Now what should I do if the user is not logged in? I'm thinking about two queryBuilders whether $userId is null or not, but it doesn't seem very clean.

Comment: I would probably use a second repository function and call that one, if userid is null. if you call your function `findOneBySlugAndUser` (or whatever) you can do `if(is_null($userid)) { return $this->findOneBySlug($slug); }` (because the `findOneBy[property]` methods are magically defined ;o))