# Doctrine many to many: count left join collection

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, many-to-many

**Note**: this is a follow up from [Doctrine many to many: has user liked the article?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57687955/doctrine-many-to-many-has-user-liked-the-article/)

Having three entities: User, Article, Comments and a "commentLikedByUser" many to many relationship between User and Comments, I need to get the comments collection from an Article, including a virtual property "userLiked" (bool) to be used on the view.

```
//CommentRepository.php
public function findCommentsFromArticle($articleId,$userId)
{
    $result = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->where('c.article = :articleId')
        ->addSelect('COUNT(u) AS userLiked', 'c')
        ->leftJoin("c.users", 'u', 'WITH', 'u.id = :userId')
        ->setParameters(['articleId' => $articleId, 'userId' => $userId])
        ->orderBy('c.id', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    dd($result);
}
```

That dumps the following:

[image]

As you can see, "userFavorite" is not in the correct position but outside of the Comment object. 
How can I fix this?

Comment: can you share the different entities déclaration ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use result of an SQL function as a field in Doctrine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35409130/is-it-possible-to-use-result-of-an-sql-function-as-a-field-in-doctrine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution using DQL.

```
public function findCommentsFromArticle($articleId, $userId)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery("select c.id,c.text, count(u) as userFavorite
from
App\Entity\Comments c
left join s.users u WITH u.id LIKE :userId 
where c.article = :articleId
group by c.id");

    $query->setParameters(['articleId' => $articleId, 'userId' => $userId]);

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

I had to manually select the columns to attach the virtual property "userFavorite". Otherwise it would be outside the object likewise.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this code:

```
//CommentRepository.php
public function findCommentsFromArticle($articleId,$userId)
{
   $result = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
    ->where('c.article = :articleId')
    ->addSelect('COUNT(u) AS userLiked', 'c')
    ->leftJoin('c.users', 'u')
    ->andWhere('u.id = :userId')
    ->setParameters(['articleId' => $articleId, 'userId' => $userId])
    ->orderBy('c.id', 'ASC')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();

dd($result);
```

}